# SQLite and Ruby on Rails on PC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am using instant rails which makes use of SQLite and I am unable to connect to the database.   I have been using a tutorial that uses MySQL and I have been unable to find instructions for SQLite. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could [install sqlite](http://blog.emson.co.uk/2008/06/installing-sqlite3-on-windows-for-rails/).
Or, assuming you have mysql installed, you could change your `config/database.yml` file to use mysql instead of sqlite.
(From using rails -d mysql testapp)

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: awesome_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
```

**Update**
To use sqlite3, you need the sqlite gem and to set up your rails database.yml to use it. The default config rails generates uses sqlite and looks like this

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

to install, here are [some good looking instructions](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/installing-and-using-sqlite-with-ruby-on-windows/)

Comment: I need the above for a SQLite database. I don't know how to get SQLite working. That's the problem.